# How can I create a "pill" SVG image in XML (by hand)?

Tags: svg, script

I need to generate an SVG image of a pill box, like so:

[image: Pill Box]

I know how to draw a circle with the `<ellipse>` element, how to draw a `<path>` element with the  `M` (moveto), `L` (lineto), and `Z` (closepath) attributes, and how to fill a shape with the `style="fill:myColor;"` attribute. What I need to do though is to start with a circle and be able to dynamically stretch it via code.

The usage is a circle over a shopping cart that will show the number of items in the user's shopping cart. I think the right way for me to do this is by defining all of the numbers in `<defs>` elements, and then dynamically including the numbers I need using `<use>` elements and setting the line lengths.

Can anyone help me on drawing this shape in code? What I get from Inkscape is multiple overlapping shapes but I'm not really very good with vector drawing programs. I think to get a code sample from Inkscape that I could examine, I'd need to break and rejoin the shapes, but I'm hoping there's a simple way or tag to just generate an arc and join them into one path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

20 second google search --> [HERE](https://codepen.io/deadlygeek/pen/KaqOPG) <-- change the `rect` width to match the height and it's a circle. Therefore, dynamically, you'd merely need to alter the `width` property to move from a circle to a pill shape.

a circle:

```
<svg version="1.1" width="1000" height="600" viewBox="0 0 16 9">
  <rect x="1" y="1" width="2" height="2" fill="silver" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.1" ry="1" rx="1"/>
</svg>
```

a pill:

```
<svg version="1.1" width="1000" height="600" viewBox="0 0 16 9">
  <rect x="1" y="1" width="4" height="2" fill="silver" stroke="black" stroke-width="0.1" ry="1" rx="1"/>
</svg>
```

SVG code from "deadlygeek" at [CodePen](https://codepen.io/deadlygeek/pen/KaqOPG)

Comment: What search terms do you use, so I get an effective search next time? I tried a number of searches and didn't get anything.

Comment: I used ---- ["convert a circle to a pill shape SVG"](https://www.google.com/search?q=convert+a+circle+to+a+pill+shape+SVG&oq=convert+a+circle+to+a+pill+shape+SVG&aqs=chrome..69i57j33.797j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) -- the link above was the fourth result.

Comment: Thanks. The terms I used were several variations of "create pill box svg", which all bring up first 100+ results of "Free icon downloads!". I didn't know what shape to convert from to a pill box - path? Two circles, lines, masks, delete nodes?